# Want to load desktop version in my webview using uastring

Tags: android, webview, user-agent

I am developing an app for tablets like samsung galaxy, moto xoom and kindle fire.

My webview is not loading the desktop version of urls which I am giving.

I tried by setting the user Agent, but I dont know whats the exact "ua string" will solve my issue. When I took log of ua string I got the following

Code :

```
String ua = m_webview.getSettings().getUserAgentString() ;
Log.i("AboutActivity", "UA = "+ua) ;
```

UA String:

```
UA = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.1; en-US; GT-P7500 Build/HMJ37) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
```

I read somewhere that I need to remove the "mobile" in the ua string but I didnt get "mobile" in the printed ua string.

I have tried the following ua string by adding desktop in it, even though its not coming

```
 String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.1; en-US; GT-P7500 Build/HMJ37) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Desktop Safari/534.13";
 mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be that they know you are on a mobile phone because you have `Android` in the user agent. Try something more desktop browser looking such as:

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me: Refer [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/6db5a76b781c636513282b9efed993e705db4570/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L358)

```
    public void setDesktopMode(final boolean enabled) {
    final WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    final String newUserAgent;
    if (enabled) {
        newUserAgent = webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("Mobile", "eliboM").replace("Android", "diordnA");
    }
    else {
        newUserAgent = webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("eliboM", "Mobile").replace("diordnA", "Android");
    }

    webSettings.setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(enabled);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(enabled);
}
```