# How to use a webview to show the page of a linkedIn contact?

Tags: android, redirect, android-webview, linkedin-api

I'm making an app that needs to show a simple webview that contains the page of a linkedIn contact.

The URL according to what i've seen is supposed to be :

```
http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=XXX
```

where XXX is the id of the contact.

For some reason, I keep getting only the logo of LinkedIn instead of the real webpage.

I thought it's because of redirection issues, but I'm not sure.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    final String url = ...
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    // needed in order to support javascript alerts and other javascript operations
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
            super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

I've tried returning false too, but it doesn't work. It's probably a very tiny mistake.

Can anyone help?

---

EDIT: seems like using the [user agent of a desktop web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310480/878126) fixed it, but now it doesn't have the same look & feel of a mobile web browser.

Comment: do you need to display the login page of linked in webview? You need to login before displaying.

Comment: if it needs to, it should show it, just like on the normal web browsers. i don't understand why it doesn't occur.

Comment: try with this link and let me know if it works https://touch.www.linkedin.com/login.html

Comment: but it doesn't contain the ID of the person. it won't be able to reach it after you connect.

Comment: u need to login. only after authentication you can go to the home page of the person

Comment: but on a normal web browser it works just fine. why would it not work on a webview?

Comment: i've just discovered that if i use the user agent of a desktop web browser, it works fine, but it doesn't look as good as the mobile web browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that I had to call:

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```